# Jquery Ajax .load() not funtional

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, html

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>jQuery UI Tabs - Collapse content</title> 
<link rel="stylesheet"
href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script>
$(function() {
$( "#tabs" ).tabs({
  collapsible: true
});
   $("#tabs-2").load("something.html");**
});
$(function() {
$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({maxDate: new Date(1997,11,31)});
});

</script>
</head>
<div id="tabs">
<ul>
<li><a href="#tabs-1">Alienware and Alpha</a></li>
<li><a href="#tabs-2">More About</a></li>
<li><a href="#tabs-3">Contact Us</a></li>
</ul>
<div id="tabs-1">
<p>blah blah</p>
</div>
<div id="tabs-2">

</div>
<div id="tabs-3">

</div>
</div> <br>
<div id="mini">
 <p><span class="italics">Please complete the form</span></p>
 <fieldset>
<form id="appForm" action="submit.php" method="post">
 **Some form details here (avoided to make the post more readable)
 </form>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

here is my something.html code:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Ajax tab 2 </title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
</head>

<body>
   <p>This is p2!!</p>
 </body>
</html>
```

I've already had a thread about this, but none of the suggestions were useful. So Im making another one. .load method does not produce any results at all. Intially i thought this was some sort of browser issue, hence i tried all possible browsers and even tried it on different OS's just to be sure. But it still doesn't work. There is no error displayed. In fact there is nothing from 'something.html' displayed on tab2(i.e "More about") at all. In brief, the .load method does not really load anything from 'something.html'

UPDATE: SOLUTION: this does not work locally, it works just fine when both the index file and 'something.html' are uploaded onto a server

Comment: OK. You're stating that your code doesn't work. However, you need to tell us what happens, what your console states, errors, network activity, etc.

Comment: It does not display any content from the 'something.html' file. its just blank tab2 (i.e"More about")

Comment: Where is something.html located, provide, what folder is it in on your website or is at the root of your website?

Comment: Is `something.html` hosted on the same server that's hosting the page requesting it? Use a complete url.

Comment: @SMcCrohan thanks for your help. I figured out that the something.html was supposed to be uploaded onto the server and could not be tested on a local computer. The people from the previous thread, told me to test it locally. Hence all the confusion. But thank you so much, you solved my 2 day's headache.

Comment: your code works locally too.. as `localhost/example`

Comment: You can absolutely test it locally and should be working locally, uploading files to a server every time you want to test a change is just not a proper development environment. To work locally you need a small server running on your machine, be it Windows IIS that comes with Windows Professional or IIS Express that will be installed with Visual Studio (Web express versions are free) You can use Web Matrix, another free Microsoft product that will run PHP or ASP.NET, you can use Apache, free, open source. Testing local DOES NOT mean running file based web pages in your browser.

Comment: The big take way here is if your browser location bar has the URL file://foo and not, localhost:123 where 123 can be any port number you are doing it wrong, development and learning speeds will be dramatically decreased if you do not know how to run a website locally

Answer (score 1):

If "something.html" is a file you've created yourself, maybe try to include that file as a link `<link href="something.html">` in the header. Not sure if it's going to work but try. 
When dealing with jQuery Ajax usually the url is where the server access the data. Get it? You probably have an external file so you try as mentioned above.

Comment: yes that was the issue, im actually surprised at how many developers told me to just modify the code, but never spotted that could be the actual issue. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Surely somebody mentioned this in your other post... but you probably have to enclose it in a `$(document).ready(`.  Otherwise, the javascript could execute before the `#tabs-2` element loads.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#tabs-2").load("something.html");
});
```

Check out the [documentation](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

I have some notes about your question:

1. If you are testing, running your files with **file protocol** (opening your files with the browser) **AJAX** (XMLHttpRequest) will not work in some browsers, such as Chrome. But if you start your local server on ***localhost*** for example, your **AJAX** requests will work properly.
2. When loading partial content, you should not include it as a full HTML document, so get rid of the *<html>* and *<body>* wrappers for your partial content. **something.html** only should contain: `<p>This is p2!!</p>`
3. If you are including scripts that depends on DOM elements at <HEAD> then you should add the `defer` attribute to your <script> tags, **OR** move your <script> tags at the end of <BODY> **OR** you should wrap your code to run when the DOM is ready:

---

```
$(document).on("ready", function() { /* CODE HERE */ });
// Shorthand for $(document).ready()
$(function() { /* CODE HERE */ });
```